# Kill a thread by name in python

Tags: python, multithreading

Is there a way to kill a thread by name in pyhton?

For example, say that I create a thread like this

```py
t = Thread(name='n', ...)
t.start()
```

Is it possible that later in my code to kill the thread with something like `killThreadByName('n')`?

Comment: There is no API in `threading` for killing a thread. *That alone* should tell you that it is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `kill()` or `stop()` in the high-level API, there's only [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) and [`is_alive()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive).

> `name` A string used for identification purposes only. It has no semantics. ***Multiple*** threads may be given the ***same*** name. The initial name is set by the constructor. ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.name))

Judging by this docstring it'd be quite unwise to kill by a name unless you can ensure it being unique e.g. by having own wrapper around `Thread.__init__()` with an `assert` or so. Meaning, the wrapper for `Thread.__init__()` will need to look *somewhere* to check such a name isn't already present. Then you can collect all of the running threads into some variable or better, a `dict`:

```py
threads = {}
threads["one"] = Thread(name="one", ...)
```

Alternatively, don't have it unique and treat the `name` as a "class"/instance of a thread doing the same thing, if you have a use-case for it. Then the killing itself would be a loop over everything with the same name and the `dict` would be something like this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
threads = defaultdict(list)
threads["one"].append(Thread(name="one", ...))
```

Otherwise, a Thread should be preferably stopped from within itself either by watching some outer variable or having a shared sharable/lockable resource which if signaled somehow to the thread would cause the thread to `exit()`/`return` or similar action leading to a clean stop that does not cause problems.

One of such resources can be [`threading.Event()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) and watching for its state [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47696709/5994041).

As to the actual thread killing, [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/323972/5994041) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403996/296803).